# What is the scope of the defined font family?

Tags: fonts, scoping

I experienced unexpected change of fonts at certain parts of my text. This was due to the fact that I did not realize that the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` environment has its own scope regarding fonts. However, I still don't understand why I get the following rendered output after compiling the following MNWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myhead}[1]{\noindent{\large\bf #1}\vspace{2mm}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily%%%Change to sans-serif font
\title{\textbf{This is a sans-serif title...}}%%%as expected
\author{\textbf{...and author...}}%%%as expected
\date{\textbf{...and date.}}%%%as expected
\clearpage\maketitle
\begin{center}%%%note that centering has its own scope regarding fonts.
\ttfamily%%%typewriter within scope
This is an url here.%%%as expected

\normalfont%%%normalfont within scope
\normalsize%%%normalfont within scope
\noindent This is normal text here, as expected.%%%as expected
\end{center}
\myhead{This heading is written in normal text, what you would intuitively expect. However, your intuition is wrong...}
%%%At first you would think that \normalfont above changes the font back to normal. But this is wrong, since it is
%%%within a \begin{center}\end{center} scope. So what you would expect that this text here will be sans-serif.
%%%But it isn't!

...since this text is still written with a sans-serif font.%%%Sans-serif font outside centering, as expected.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is the heading given by `\myhead{}` is rendered with `\normalfont`, and not with `\sffamily` as specified? What is the rule here?

Comment: fonts are active as long as they are in group. An environment is a group. You have explicitly used `{\large bf}` inside. that's why it's scoped

Comment: I am sorry, I don't follow you. I agree, that I have specified `{\large bf}`, but should not it still be typeset with `\sffamily`? Is there an implicit `\normalfont` call because of `\large` and/or `\bf`?

Comment: Perhaps I am not following you. The text after the `center` environment` is continuing with sans serif, except your `\myhead` command of course, which switches temporarily to `\bf`. I expect a sans serif after `\myhead` (due to how you defined it). Omit the `{...}` around `\large bf #1` and the `\bf` leaks to the end

Comment: Let me try again. I set `\sffamily` in the beginning, so I expect that all following text will be of this type. I override this *within the scope of* `\begin{center}\end{center}` and once I am out of that scope I once again expect that the font family is `\sffamily`. This is exactly the reason why the very last sentence is typeset with `\sffamily` font. What I don't understand is that why the text within `\myhead{}` is *not* `\sffamily`?

Comment: Now I got you: `\bf` is not the same as `\textbf` or `\bfseries`

Comment: Ah, I see then. Then I need to look up what are the differences.

Comment: unrelated to the question really but you shouldn't have any formatting commands like `\textbf` in the argument to structural commands like `\title`, also `\noindent` does nothing inside `center`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle should I write `\textbf{\title{...}}` instead?

Comment: No!!!! you should write `\title` the formatting of titles should be specified elsewhere, preferably in your document class or perhaps overridden in the preamble. if you have explicit font changes in the document it's usually a sign that something is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\bf` does not maintain the font family, except being used in an explicit group `{...}` or an environment.

Use the safer `\bfseries` for this to be sure!!!!

This is one reason why the `\bf` ,`\it`, `\sc`, `\tt` and `\rm` shouldn't be used any longer -- they are deprecated since 1993.

See the differences in the output of the following code: (I did not clean up, however!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myhead}[1]{\noindent{\large\bfseries #1}\vspace{2mm}}

\newcommand{\myotherhead}[1]{\noindent{\large\bf #1}\vspace{2mm}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily%%%Change to sans-serif font
\title{\textbf{This is a sans-serif title...}}%%%as expected
\author{\textbf{...and author...}}%%%as expected
\date{\textbf{...and date.}}%%%as expected
\clearpage\maketitle
\begin{center}%%%note that centering has its own scope regarding fonts.
\ttfamily%%%typewriter within scope
This is an url here.%%%as expected

\normalfont%%%normalfont within scope
\normalsize%%%normalfont within scope
\noindent This is normal text here, as expected.%%%as expected
\end{center}
\myhead{This heading is written in normal text, what you would intuitively expect. However, your intuition is wrong...}
%%%At first you would think that \normalfont above changes the font back to normal. But this is wrong, since it is
%%%within a \begin{center}\end{center} scope. So what you would expect that this text here will be sans-serif.
%%%But it isn't!

...since this bold text is still written with a sans-serif font now.%%%Sans-serif font outside centering, as expected.


\myotherhead{This heading is written in normal text, what you would intuitively expect. However, your intuition is wrong...}
%%%At first you would think that \normalfont above changes the font back to normal. But this is wrong, since it is
%%%within a \begin{center}\end{center} scope. So what you would expect that this text here will be sans-serif.
%%%But it isn't!

...since this bold text is not written with a sans-serif font!

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

A small sample document that shows that `\bf` switches back to roman font:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand\sampletext{The quick brown fox jumps}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\showfamily}{\f@family}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sffamily 

\sampletext


Output: \showfamily

\bf \sampletext 

Output after \verb!\bf!: \showfamily


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, I think I got you. Yes, indeed, the `\bf` call overrides the font family back to `\normalfont`, and its effect is localized within the encapsulating `{...}`.

Comment: I am speculating here, but since you have changed the very last line, satrting with `...since this text is **not** written...` you expect that it is rendered with `\normalfont`. If I compile your example then it is *still* using `\ssfamily`. I think your intentions were to remove the encapsulating `{...}` around your `{\large\bf #1}`.

Comment: @Matsmath: Yes, `\bfseries` will keep the family

Comment: @Matsmath: Yes, I did wrong pasting and was confused ;-)

Comment: I copy-pasted your code *above* (so the first one), and then compiled. The last sentence is a paradox: it claims wrongfully that *...since this text is not written with a sans-serif font any longer.* but actually it *is* written wit ha sans-serif font.

Comment: Can you check the last sentence of your first picture? It looks sans-serif font to me, contrary to what the text says.

Comment: @Matsmath: Well, I was just too lazy. And I edited my code in between! And look at the text: `this bold text....`